# Difference between 'sudo apt-get' and 'sudo -E apt-get'

Tags: apt, updates, sudo, vmware

I'm using Ubuntu 15.10 guest on VMWare Player (7.1.3 build-3206955), with Windows 10 as the host OS. I'm able to use Firefox to browse the web inside the guest, however I'm unable to use `apt` on the terminal.
Whenever i invoke the command `sudo apt-get update`, it gets stuck at `0% [connecting to in.archive.ubuntu.com]`, finally failing. Also, using `sudo apt-get install <package>` always results in the package not even being found.
On the other hand, using the same commands with the `-E` flag on sudo makes them work.
Can somebody explain what's happening here?

**EDIT**: I forgot to add that i'm using multiple internet connections; one with proxy and one without. Regular sudo works on the one without proxy but not on the one with it.

Comment: Hey i don't have the line above, instead there's `Defaults env_reset` in the file.

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/178303/how-does-sudo-e-work-here

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The magic word here is `proxy`. In your environment you will have proxy information set that allows you to access the internet.

The environment variable `http_proxy` contains your proxy settings.
Execute `echo $http_proxy` to see them (maybe `$HTTP_PROXY`).

If you run `sudo <command>`, the command will be executed in its own environment as `root`. If you add the `-E` option to `sudo`, the command will be executed as `root`, but with most of your environment copied over.

You can check that by executing the following three commands:

- `env`
- `sudo env`
- `sudo -E env`

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. However, i also happen to use Ubuntu 15.04 where regular `sudo` with or without proxy being set. Setting and unsetting proxy from system settings and then applying system wide changes the env for both `sudo env` and regular `env`, too. I noticed that clicking on the 'Apply system wide' button in Ubuntu 15.04 results in the OS asking for root password while this does not happen in Ubuntu 15.10; could this be the reason?

Comment: @AdityaSrivastava I don't know whether there is a difference between Ubuntu 15.04 and Ubuntu 15.10 or that you have set up Ubuntu 15.10 different from Ubuntu 15.04. Asking for the password to 'Apply System Wide' is expected because it affects the whole system (i.e. all users) and not just you. This is not related to `sudo -E`. There probably is a setting somewhere that allows you to disable asking for the password.

Comment: @AdityaSrivastava What is also possible is that you've done another operation first that required entering your password. The 'sudo status' is 'remembered' for a specific time. If you perform another 'sudo' operation before the time expires, you don't have to re-enter your password. The default time is 15 minutes in Ubuntu. See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudoTimeout

Comment: Well, i guess that'll make for another question then. I believe this is the right answer for now. Thanks.